# PowerBI Count all Rows With Value In Group

Tags: powerbi, dax

This seems like one of the use cases for groups, but maybe I'm understanding them wrong.

I have a table that shows a count of all rows like this:

```
User | Completed Tasks
Bob  | 2
Jim  | 1
Pete | 1
```

The table it comes from looks like this:

```
User | Type
Bob  | A
Bob  | B
Jim  | A
Pete | C
```

This is very simplified - in reality there are about 80 different types - I'm hoping to get 5 of them in a group called `Secondary` and the rest in a group called `Primary`

For the example, say I want A and B to be considered "primary" and C to be secondary.

The new table would look like this:

```
User | Completed Tasks | Primary | Secondary
Bob  |        2        |    2    |     0
Jim  |        1        |    1    |     0   
Pete |        1        |    0    |     1
```

I tried creating a group of `Type` with 5 called `Secondary` and the rest called `Primary`, but I was having trouble figuring it out.

I just want a Count of types for that particular group based on the filtered values and everything.

Is there an easy way to do this or do I need to create a measure/calculated column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by creating two calculated columns.

The Dax for the primary would be a `1` for each row not in the Secondary list:

```
PrimaryCount = IF(table[Type] in {"C","D","E","F","G"},0,1)
```

The Dax for the secondary would be a `1` for each row IN the Secondary list:

```
SecondaryCount = IF(table[Type] in {"C","D","E","F","G"},1,0)
```

Then, just add those to your table values and make sure `Sum` is selected (the default).

I figured using groups would be easier, but I suppose this is simple enough and seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this is to create a calculated column for `Group`

```
Group = IF(table[Type] IN {"A","B"}, "Primary", "Secondary")
```

You can then use the `Group` as the columns on a matrix and count the `Type` column.

[image: Matrix Visual]

Note that this approach scales better if you want to break into a lot more groups. You'd likely want to use a `SWITCH` in that case like this:

```
Group = 
    SWITCH(TRUE(),
        Table1[Type] IN {"A","B"}, "Primary",
        Table1[Type] IN {"C"}, "Secondary",
        Table1[Type] IN {"D", "E", "F"}, "Tertiary",
        "Other"
    )
```

Comment: This looks awesome - maybe more what I was looking for. Thanks for your reply